# Print Font details next to Each element in Exported Artwork in Adobe XD

Tags: adobe-xd

Is it possible to export an artwork in Adobe XD with Font details of each text element printed near each respective text element.

(This would avoid the inconvenient process of clicking each text and then scroll right sidebar to see font details.)

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: @Mensch Thanks. I see you are a very senior member here. Can you please comment on my query...is it possible in Adobe XD?